# I can't close fancybox using webdriver

Tags: webdriver, fancybox

I have a problem closing a Fancybox using selenium Webdriver. On the fancy-box is a big "X" located for closing it[http://tinypic.com/r/2w3xq1f/8].

I tried this but without success:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-item fancybox-close")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/a")).click();
```

PS: Please see snapshot

Comment: this is the source code of the "X" closing Element:
<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"/>

Comment: Can you use css selector of X button to close it ? That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct XPATH selector

e.g.

```
`driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"]')).click();`
```

For more information, look at: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I used css selector of X button to close it but with no success

Comment: I used css selector of X button to close it but with no success, but i can't understand the href tag with javascript as value (href="javascript:;"), maybe it has to do with a javascript function or something similar

Comment: Try debugging for see the result of findElement()

Comment: @Witold...I've done it before and unfortunately without success

Comment: @Subh: i copied the code you send, but after not finding the webelement, it goes to the catch 
Block and throws an exception for not founding the webelemnt

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code to wait 10 seconds for the visibility of 'Close' element and then clicking on it to close:**

```
try{
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Close']")));
    element.click();
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Element wasn't found: "+e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is in new frame, try driver.switchTo().frame